# I don't understand what is wrong with this code

Tags: python, python-2.5

I get an error on the following code and I don't understand what is wrong with it.

I am just trying to learn how to do this, and this was a test.

I can't figure out what is wrong or how to fix it.

```
print "Would you like to see today's weather?"

answer = input

if answer = "yes":
    print "Follow Link: http://www.weather.com/weather/right-now/Yorktown+VA+23693 "
elif answer = "no":
    print "Very well, would you like to play a guessing game?"
    if answer = "yes":
        import random

        secret = random.randint (1, 99)
        guess= 0
        tries= 0

        print "AHOY!  I'm the Dread Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!"
        print "It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries. "

        while guess != secret and tries < 6:
            guess = input("What's your guess? ")
            if guess < secret:
                print "Too low, ye scurvy dog!"
            elif guess > secret:
                print "Too high, landlubber!"
            tries = tries + 1
            if guess == secret:
                print "Avast! Ye got it! Found my secret ye did!"
    elif answer = "no":
        print "Thank you, and goodnight."
```

Comment: What error do you get? Where do you get it?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Please add a description of your problem to the original post.

Comment: exactly user 1938922 what is the error

Comment: invalid syntax cause your using assignment operator in if

Comment: I think you want `answer = input()`

Answer (score 5):

**First** error is here :

```
if answer = "yes": #This would be giving you a syntax error
```

What you want to do is a comparison (same for every test case, in your code):

```
if answer == "yes": #Notice the double equals to sign
```

---

**Also,**  you want to call the input function :

```
answer = input() #Notice the parentheses
```

---

**Third**  error (This is a logical one) :

```
print "Very well, would you like to play a guessing game?"
#You are missing an input statemtent
if answer = "yes":
```

---

**Then again,**  same error :

```
print "It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries. "
#You are agin missing an input statement
while guess != secret and tries < 6:
```

Comment: @Dolda2000 Made the change. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what AshRj pointed out, here are two more obvious errors:

```
answer = input
```

This will assign the actual function "`input`" to `answer`, not call the function. Also, you probably want to use `raw_input` instead. So, use `answer = raw_input()`.

```
elif answer = "no":
    print "Very well, would you like to play a guessing game?"
    if answer = "yes":
```

You're not fetching a new answer between those comparisons, so `answer` will still be `no` when you test it again.